# How To Find The Difference Between Two .tif Files

Tags: c#, image, vb6, picturebox, scanning

The background for this problem is as follows: There is an old VB scanning application, for which I do not have the source code, that creates a .tif file out on a web-site's remote directory. ImageConvert.exe (used as part of a CGI-based web application) will convert that .tif file to a .gif file.

A newer C# application acquires an image from a scanner, and initializes a PictureBox object with it. Eventually, the image is saved out to a share from the PictureBox object, like so:

```
private PictureBox m_scanned_pic = new PictureBox();
.
.
.
    catch
    {
       file_exists = false;
       test_file = new FileStream(image_path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
       test_file.Close();
       test_file.Dispose();
       test_file = null;
       m_scanned_pic.Image.Save(image_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }
```

When run through ImageConvert.exe, no conversion takes place, and there is no error. I want to find the differences between the .tif that ImageConvert.exe can convert and the .tif file that doesn't convert. I'm stuck. Both .tif images look fine to me visually.

Comment: These images are *supposed* to be exactly the same, right?

Comment: Depending on the type of tiff you are getting, they could vary widely.  A TIFF can act as a container file that could contain different types of images. Apps that support TIF vary in their support of different compression in tiffs (group 3, group 4, LZW, zip,...).  You could use a binary diff and look at the headers, which might help you figure out the differences.

Comment: @bokibeg Unfortunately, they are not both the same, because I cannot get hold of the original item that was scanned.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I will find a binary diff tool. Thanks.

Comment: There are tools that will let you see the tags of the tiff to determine what compression, color depth, and resolution are set for them.  More useful than a binary diff tool, unless you know how to read the binary of the tif format.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Crazy Pixels produces ImageConvert.exe. It's freeware.

The problem appears to be that the older version of ImageConvert.exe (2002) doesn't deal with LZW compression. The newer version does.

The web site that displays the Permits images (.tif files) uses ImageConvert.exe to render a .tif to a .gif and change the width while preserving aspect.